# Working with npm packages in SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, pnp, typescript, office-dev-pnp, npm

I am starting to work on a SP 2013 hosted app. I am planning to use typescript and have setup my project with Typescript configurations enabled. I have created a SP module called "dist" and all typescript files are transpiled to JavaScript and placed inside that module and later gets deployed to SP by default hosted app feature based implementation.

Now my question is how can I get my packages (mainly @pnp/pnpjs) in node_modules folder imported into the "dist" module. what's the best mechanism to ensure all my import statement packages are properly uploaded to SharePoint?

Comment: if there's no issue with firewalls and corporate policies, you can use CDN's

Comment: if I use CDN the module resolution using import statement does not work.It tries to get for eg: pnpjs from a relative path inside the app's deployed folder structure.